# Would it be bad to have a bunch of UiViews on screen at once

Tags: ios, uiview, core-text, cgrect

So I'm working in Core Text and have made a CTFrame and placed it on the screen. I also need a way to move the frame around and delete it which CTFrame doesn't seem to do.

I wanted to place the CTFrame in a CGRect but I can't, because i need a context which a CGRect obviously does not have.

My question is, would it be bad to have text snippets stored in a few UIViews on screen? That way I can completely control movement and deletion through a UIView itself.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely have many dozens of views on the screen at once. It's not an issue.